# Datatable filter jquery, ajax, .net?

Tags: jquery, filter, datatable

I am interested in adding additional filters to my datatable (search results) in order to narrow down existing search results. Something similar to filters used by amazon, ebay or booking.com

Is there a control on the market that actually supports this or it is always a custom made control/solution.

examples
http://www.booking.com/searchresults.en-gb.html?label=opensearch-plugin;sid=35c9991ea7eb100b6bd46a997602103f;class_interval=1;offset=0;score_min=0;si=ai,co,ci,re,di;ss_all=0;;city=-2601889;origin=disamb;srhash=2888651729;srpos=1

http://cell-phones.shop.ebay.com/Cell-Phone-PDA-Accessories-/20336/i.html?_nkw=htc+desire&_catref=1&_dmpt=PDA_Accessories&_fln=1&_trksid=p3286.c0.m282

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for but the [Datatables](http://www.datatables.net/) jQuery plugin should do exactly what you're looking for.  It works with JSON objects and filtering is simple to use and customize.  You should definitely check it out.